# How to find the default style of EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

I want to see what exactly the default style for `EditText` defines. So the first step for me is to figure out, which style is actually the default one.

Checking the `EditText` [source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/EditText.java) I found this:

```
public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.editTextStyle);
}
```

I think this means the default style is defined as `com.android.internal.R.attr.editTextStyle`. But where can I find the implementation of this style? And why is it R.**attr**.editTextStyle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attr means `AttributeSet` - special set with params of `View`s which is passed in constructor and parsed there. it contains all attributes set by XML or default set when just-`Context` constructor is used. `com.android.internal.R.attr.editTextStyle` (and all other `R.`) are just integer pointers, probably handled in lower layer (`View`?) extended by `TextView`

note that `com.android.internal.R.attr.editTextStyle` is just pointer to style defined by system, so it may differ across versions (especially before Material Design, so 4.x). for example in [THIS](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/themes_material.xml) source `editTextStyle` is pointing further on Material Design depended (line 244)

```
<item name="editTextStyle">@style/Widget.Material.EditText</item>
```